# Menu and Submenu Display Mechanism

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to implement a mechanism to display sub-menus when I click on an item in the main menu of my Angular application.

The issue I'm facing is that when I click on an item in the main menu, like `Agences`, I want that item to be hidden to make room for the sub-menu, for example, `Portefeuilles`.

Illustration:

[image]

I click on `Agences`

[image]

The `Agences` section should disappear and make way for the sub-menu.

[image]

I'm unable to solve my problem. Could you please guide me on how to resolve it?

**online.ts**

```
export class OnlineComponent implements OnInit {
  nav: IMenuItem[] = [];

  constructor(private onlineService: OnlineService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Initialize the 'nav' property with data from the 'onlineService'
    this.nav = this.onlineService.IMenuItem;
  }

  toggleSubMenu(index: number) {
    // Toggle the active state of the clicked item
    this.nav[index].active = !this.nav[index].active;

    // Ensure that all other items are deactivated
    for (let i = 0; i < this.nav.length; i++) {
      if (i !== index) {
        this.nav[i].active = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**online.html**

```
<div class="container text-center" *ngIf="nav">
    <div class="sideBar">
      <div class="menu-content">
        <ul class="menu-items">
          <li class="item" *ngFor="let menuItem of nav; let i = index">
            <div class="menu-item" (click)="toggleSubMenu(i)">
              <!-- Display the menu item name -->
              <span class="title">{{ menuItem.name }}</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu" *ngIf="menuItem.active">
              <li class="subitem" *ngFor="let subItem of menuItem.sub">
                <div class="submenu-item">
                  <!-- Add [routerLink] directive to manage navigation -->
                  <a [routerLink]="subItem.state">{{ subItem.name }}</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <!-- This is where the routed components will be displayed -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

For your information, my code is available on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ekafl2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fviews%2Fonline%2Fonline.component.html).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the menu item when it is active. But you don't have an option to close the menu then. Is that fine for you?

```
<div class="container text-center" *ngIf="nav">
    <div class="sideBar">
      <div class="menu-content">
        <ul class="menu-items">
          <li class="item" *ngFor="let menuItem of nav; let i = index">
            <div class="menu-item" [hidden]="menuItem.active" (click)="toggleSubMenu(i)">
              <!-- Display the menu item name -->
              <span class="title">{{ menuItem.name }}</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu" *ngIf="menuItem.active">
              <li class="subitem" *ngFor="let subItem of menuItem.sub">
                <div class="submenu-item">
                  <!-- Add [routerLink] directive to manage navigation -->
                  <a [routerLink]="subItem.state">{{ subItem.name }}</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <!-- This is where the routed components will be displayed -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```